# Auto Complete suggestion not working under widget layouts

Tags: android, android-widget, android-cardview

After updating studio to SDK 23 it is not showing any auto suggestions inside widget layouts.

Like   `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` or `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` inside these layouts not getting any auto suggestions but after closing the widgets auto suggestion is working properly.

Why this is happening? I tried deleting cache, built files updating gradle files again but nothing working.

Is it issue with 23?

For more understanding check these two images:

1) **when my Relative Layout is inside of card view widget it is not
   showing any suggestion on Ctrl+space**

[image]

**2) But outside of card widget layout it is showing suggestion on Ctrl+space**

[image]

Comment: share your code here

Comment: @VinayJayaram check my updated question.

Comment: Did you try restarting your android studio?

Comment: @VinayJayaram  cleared cache with studio restart .

Comment: May i know which version cardview you are using?

Comment: @VinayJayaram  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'

Comment: Invalidate Cache/Restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue in android, Try changing
 **com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0 to com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1**

NOTE: make sure you Invalidate & restart your android studio